# Overlay scroll poor performance with body overflow hidden on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, scroll

I want to prevent body scrolling if overlay is shown. And I use lazyload for the list elements, which means scroll event listener takes a little while. (replaced with an empty loop in code below.)

However, setting `overflow: hidden` results in overlay scroll poor performance, or at least not as good as the other, in Chrome 83 on Windows (with touthpad) and Android, but Firefox Android seems good.

How does `overflow: hidden` make the difference? How can I prevent performance impact?

**Edit:** poor performance means there is a notable delay when scrolling. The scroll is not smooth, you can feel the content *jumping*, which is bad user experience.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #scroll-container {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 60vw;
        background-color: aliceblue;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
      #body-content {
        background-color: antiquewhite;
      }
      #toggle {
        position: fixed;
        top: 1em;
        left: 1em;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
      window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        for (const parent of [$("#scroll-content"), $("#body-content")]) {
          for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            const p = document.createElement("p");
            p.innerText = "paragraph" + i;
            parent.appendChild(p);
          }
        }
        $('#toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
          const current = $('body').style.overflowY
          $('body').style.overflowY = current ? '' : 'hidden' 
        })
        $('#scroll-container').addEventListener('scroll', () => {
          for (let i = 0; i < 200000000; i++);
        })
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body-content"></div>
    <button id="toggle">Toggle Overflow</button>
    <div id="scroll-container">
      <div id="scroll-content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use javascript to set the css for the body whenever the modal is shown/hidden without using the `overflow` property at all.

```
// When the content is shown, we want a fixed body
document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
document.body.style.top = `-${window.scrollY}px`;

// When the content is hidden or closed...
const scrollY = document.body.style.top;
document.body.style.position = '';
document.body.style.top = '';
window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(scrollY || '0') * -1);
```

The second line of code captures the current position on the `body` when the modal/overlay is open. Otherwise, the default action is to scroll all the way up to the top when it's closed. If that's the behavior you want, feel free to leave it out. Most of the second group of code is just to move the view back to the correct position in the `body`. It can be simplified to use only the second line there, if you want to leave the user at the top.

Comment: I end up swapping first and second line, and it works! I will gladly accept this answer if you can briefly explain why `overflow` would impact the performance.

Comment: @AllanChain I'm not sure what you mean by "performance"... either it scrolls or it doesn't. The `overflow: hidden` property doesn't allow for scrolling. Use `overflow: scroll` when you want to be able to scroll the content of the element.

Comment: It's likely due to your lazyload constantly resizing the content while you're scrolling. Try using a promise to load your items, then adding them in all at once after the content is prepared. With a large amount of data, the smaller processors in mobile devices will take longer to process.

Comment: Anything more than this is really beyond the scope of your original question. And FFR, you should keep to asking one question per post, lest the mods flag you.

Comment: @erelsong You still misundertand me... I mean it is smooth without overflow hidden, while it's not smooth with overflow hidden. Anyway, it works and I will accept this answer.